# How to do custom routing in asp.net core 2.1 identity ui?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, mvcrazor

When i am adding route "/Poster/animals_institute/animals_in_trees/research_about_frogs_in_trees" and redirecting to "Dashboard" page using following code then it's working fine.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Dashboard");
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Dashboard", "/Game/animals_institute/animals_in_trees/research_about_frogs_in_trees");
});
}
```

But that's static routing i need to change it with dynamic routes and access these route value in .cs file. Like routes can be following:

```
/Game/animals_institute/animals_in_trees/research_about_frogs_in_trees
/Game/birds_institute/birds_on_trees/research_about_dove
/Game/animals_institute/know/know_about_cat_in_trees
/Game/animals_institute/show/show_cat_results
/Game/men_institute/men_in_society/know_about_man_in_hospital
```

How can i do this type of custom routing in asp.net core 2.1 identity ui

Comment: You can manage this using RouteBuilder 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @NileshVishwakarma: i don't have controllers and actions methods in my application, I have only .cshtml and .cshtml.cs pages. Do you have any idea about it.

Comment: @Manjt, no idea. but may be this link is help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.1 .
Check "Model conventions", "Page route action conventions" topic

Comment: Do you want to route all of the URLs you provided to the same Page?

Comment: Yeas @KirkLarkin. But i successfully achieved this functionality. You can check the answer of this question .

Comment: I need to know what's up with those URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Just add route using AddPageRoute method like the following code:

options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Game", "/Game/{client}/{event}/{title}");

and you can pass any link like
"http://localhost:64643/Game/animals_institute/animals_in_trees/research_about_frogs_in_trees" 
or
"http://localhost:64643//Game/birds_institute/birds_on_trees/research_about_dove"